# Deleting items more than 1 day old from sql database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to remove items that are created more than 1 day old, however all my items still remain.  I am certain that the changes are committed to my database since I am using the `RemoveItem` method in other locations as well.

```
    using (var db = new CommerceEntities())
    {
        DateTime checkexpiryDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1);
        var itemstoDelete = from c in db.ShoppingCarts
                            where c.DateCreated < checkexpiryDate
                            select new
                                   {
                                       c.CartID,
                                       c.ProductID,
                                       c.Color,
                                       c.Size,
                                   };

        foreach (var item in itemstoDelete)
        {
            try
            {
                //remove item code....
                //RemoveItem(string cartID, int productID, string color, string size)
            }

        public void RemoveItem(string cartID, int productID, string color, string size)
        {
            using (var db = new CommerceEntities())
            {
                ....
                ..
                //db.DeleteObject(myItem);
                ....
                ..
                //db.SaveChanges();
                ...
                ....
                ..
             }
}
```

Comment: Are you committing the changes, as I don't see it from the above code sample.

Comment: Break this down into pieces, and work out which pieces work and which don't - does `itemsToDelete` return any items? If not, then it's a fault in the query you've shown. If it *does* return items, the fault is in the code you haven't shown us.

Comment: Yes the changes are committed, I am certain as other locations are using this piece of method.

Comment: I see you've edited in more code - but we're unable to run this code, you are. You're much better placed to work out which parts are working and which aren't. (Using a debugger, or print statements, or anything)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO, the preferred way to do that would be TSQL, not an ORM

```
declare @when datetime = GETUTCDATE() - 1
delete from ShoppingCarts where DateCreated < @when
```

which is trivial to execute via either ADO.NET or any helper utility.

that avoids dragging an unknown amount of data over the wire, and avoids a lengthy transaction while you perform multiple discreet operations.

Answer (score 0):

Entity framework right?

```
db.DeleteObject(item);

db.SaveChanges();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386870.aspx

You need to select an actual element, it's not exactly clear what you are trying to delete.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat obvious question but could be your problem: are you certain your dates in the database are in UTC format?

Other things you might like to try are sharing the code in your "try" statement (I assume something is actually happening in there and you've just left it out) and also using SQL Profiler to take a look at what's executing on the SQL Server, both in the original select statement and subsequent deletations.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried with and without UTC, both giving me the same results.

Comment: So back to the second part of the question, what are you seeing in SQL Profiler?